# Under the hood, how does rxjs listen for changes

Tags: rxjs, event-listener

Since browsers' DOM API works via an event loop and to listen for changes on the dom we register event handlers.

What does RXJS behind the scene implement for subscribers to listen for changes in data.

I could be entirely missing the plot here. (I use them day to day but would like to know under the hood how they work with the DOM APIs).

I understand observer pattern but that is a design abstraction, how the core RXJS operates with the DOM is what I am looking for.

Comment: Have answered with the "straight forward" way. For more - you need to do a "research value"(from StackOverflow rules) about schedulers(example - docs: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward way would take a look at source code: [`fromEvent`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/fromEvent.ts) as you want to see DOM interaction and [schedulers](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src/internal/scheduler) for DOM API(setInterval, for example)

Answer (score 0):

**Observables** are just **functions**. They do not provide anything special under the hood, they just offer whatever the Javascript platform, browser or node, offers with a different powerful paradigm. The power of RxJS lays in the rich set of functions and operators which can be composed in transformation pipelines. This is where the magic of Observables comes from.

Consider the following example which wraps the `readline` function provided by the `fs` module of **Node**.

```
const readLineObs = (filePath: string): Observable<string> => {
  return Observable.create(
    (observer: Observer<string>): TeardownLogic => {
      const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
      });

      rl.on("line", (line: string) => {
        observer.next(line);
      });
      rl.on("close", () => {
        observer.complete();
      });
    }
  );
};
```

This code relies on Node apis to do the work of reading a file line by line, but offers the result as an Observable. The advantage is that you can use the Observable operators to process the results, like in the following example

```
readLinesObs('my_path_to_file').pipe(
  filter(line => line[0] === 'A'), // take only the lines which start with A
  map((line, i) => i + '_' + line),  // add a line number at the start of the line
  take(10),  // just take the first 10 lines
  // do all other types of transformations you may need
)
```